# Using an If Statement with a Piping Command

Tags: powershell

I'm completely new to using PowerShell and computer programming in general. I'm trying to create a script that kills a process(firefox in this case) if it exceeds a working set of 10mb. I would like to do this using an if statement and also having a piping command included. So far I have this:

```
get-process|where-object {$_.ProcessName -eq"firefox"}

if ($_.WorkingSet -gt10000000)
      {kill}
else
       {"This process is not using alot of the computers resources"}
```

Can anyone help to fix this? Even though firefox is exceeding 10MB working set, the else statement is always reproduced.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the conditional in a loop:

```
Get-Process | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq 'firefox' } | % {
  if ($_.WorkingSet -gt 10MB) {
    kill $_
  } else {
    "This process is not using alot of the computers resources"
  }
}
```

Otherwise the conditional would be evaluated independently from the pipeline, which means that the current object variable (`$_`) would be empty at that point.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the process in question by using the Name parameter (no need to use `Where-Object` for this purpose) then pipe the objects to the `Stop-Process` cmdlet. Notice the `-WhatIf` switch, it shows what would happen if the cmdlet runs (the cmdlet is not run). Remove it to execute the cmdlet.

```
Get-Process -Name firefox | 
Where-Object {$_.WorkingSet -gt 10mb} | 
Stop-Process -WhatIf
```

Comment: +1. I upvoted both answers, but this is really a more powershell-ish way of handling such situations. I'd give this a +2 if I could. :)